# C# - Threads are really slow

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to load content in a different thread.

When I call the Load-Method normally, I get a loading time of ~0.6 Seconds

```
public void Load()
{
   TLoad();
}
private void TLoad()
{
   [....]
}
```

But if I call the TLoad() method using a Thead Object, I get unbelievable high loading times

```
Thread loadthread;
public void Load()
{
   loadthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TLoad));
   loadthread.Start();
}
private void TLoad()
{
   [....]
}
```

which last about 12 up to 30 times longer than the normal loading time. (7-27 sec)

I've already tried to set Thread.Priotity to ThreadPriority.High etc., but the performance didn't increase.

Comment: Are you in `Debug`? Are you running with the *debugger attached?* Are you using a `Stopwatch` to validate the times?

Comment: No, I am not in Debug. And: I'm using the difference of `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` to validate the times.

Comment: Using `DateTime` to measure performance is a common mistake. `DateTime` is not precise. Use `Stopwatch` instead

Comment: Well, Sriram, some common sense. DateTime is not really really precise, but when the thing runs from 0.6 to 27 seconds I would assume the fact that DateTime has a granularity of about 0.025 seconds IIRC is quite absolutely totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using a profiler.

It is quite wrong to say the thread is slow when the processing is. Seriously. The thread overhead will be quite zero.

Likely you do something in TLoad that is not thread safe - sadly it is the code you insist on not showing. HTML requests for example may line up with only X per domain executing at the same time. A profiler would show you this.

Comment: Yes, the ContentManager in XNA seems to be the problem. But I am kind of annoyed because I dont use it in any other thread than in the one which calles LoadT.. this was the reason why I thought it would be "semi-thread-safe" in a way.. but its strange that even things which dont have to do anything with the ContentManager seem to be much slower as well. E.g. Map Generation.
I wasnt posting the code because I thought that it would be quite irrelevant because I havn't thought that i'd use not thread safe objects and that it has to do something with the scheduler.